# Connectors or Bots: which one to use?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Connectors allow posting message to a specific channel.  Bots allow posting proactive messages to a channel.  I feel that if I am only posting notifications, Connectors should suffice. I would like to understand the use case for both a little better.

Comment: Along with the below links, you can also refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-activity-feed-notifications-best-practices to help understand better.

Answer (score 2):

Find more on this conversation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/544432/connectors-or-bots-which-one-to-use.html):

[Sharon Zhao MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/610085/sharonzhao-msft.html) Moderator posted:

> > "I feel that if I am only posting notifications, Connectors should
> > suffice"
>
> You’re right.
>
> For more information, please refer to the **Bots for private chats and
> channels** and **Custom connectors** parts in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/deploy-apps-microsoft-teams-landing-page).

My reply:

> I would think that this depends on the availability of the update then
> determine a correct way to deliver it i.e. if server doesn't push any
> notifications then it would have to be a Bot.

Comment: Right, Sharing more links to understand it more properly- Refer this for [Webhooks and Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors) and [Designing your Microsoft Teams bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/design/bots)